# how to use spellcheck in solarium

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I want to use spellcheck in solarium but I'm having trouble working with it

I've got the following code from [solarium's documentation](https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/queries/select-query/building-a-select-query/components/spellcheck-component/)

```
<?php

require(__DIR__.'/init.php');
htmlHeader();

// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

// get a select query instance
$query = $client->createSelect();
$query->setRows(0);

// add spellcheck settings
$spellcheck = $query->getSpellcheck();
$spellcheck->setQuery('tes');
$spellcheck->setCount(10);
$spellcheck->setBuild(true);
$spellcheck->setCollate(true);
$spellcheck->setExtendedResults(true);
$spellcheck->setCollateExtendedResults(true);

// this executes the query and returns the result
$resultset = $client->select($query);
$spellcheckResult = $resultset->getSpellcheck();

echo '<h1>Correctly spelled?</h1>';
if ($spellcheckResult->getCorrectlySpelled()) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}

echo '<h1>Suggestions</h1>';
foreach ($spellcheckResult as $suggestion) {
    echo 'NumFound: '.$suggestion->getNumFound().'<br/>';
    echo 'StartOffset: '.$suggestion->getStartOffset().'<br/>';
    echo 'EndOffset: '.$suggestion->getEndOffset().'<br/>';
    echo 'OriginalFrequency: '.$suggestion->getOriginalFrequency().'<br/>';
    foreach ($suggestion->getWords() as $word) {
        echo '-----<br/>';
        echo 'Frequency: '.$word['freq'].'<br/>';
        echo 'Word: '.$word['word'].'<br/>';
    }

    echo '<hr/>';
}

$collations = $spellcheckResult->getCollations();
echo '<h1>Collations</h1>';
foreach ($collations as $collation) {
    echo 'Query: '.$collation->getQuery().'<br/>';
    echo 'Hits: '.$collation->getHits().'<br/>';
    echo 'Corrections:<br/>';
    foreach ($collation->getCorrections() as $input => $correction) {
        echo $input . ' => ' . $correction .'<br/>';
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}

htmlFooter();
```

But it does not work and I see the error below

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCorrectlySpelled() on null

I use `solr 4.4.0` and `solarium 3.3.0`

What is your solution?